# JavaPairInputDstream stream from offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to save my offsets to zookeeper when using spark direct streaming. I see **JavaInputDstream** API has got an option to start from a specific offset but I need it for **JavaPairInputDstream** Is there way workaround we can use to get JavaPairInputDstream as I see it is not available in the API

```
JavaInputDStream<String>  messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jsc, String.class,
                            String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, String.class, kafkaParams, offsets,(messageAndMetadata) -> messageAndMetadata.message());
```

but I use JavaPairInputDstream which doesn't have this offset

Answer (score 0):

I did a transform in the direct stream and map to a key-value pair.

```
  final JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages2 =messages.transformToPair(pairRdd -> {

                            pairRdd.mapToPair(label->new Tuple2<>(label,label))};);
```